# Отображение пустой страницы при подключении jQuery-плагина

Tags: jquery

Всем, привет! На странице есть куча подключенных плагинов jQuery, какой за что отвечает понять сложно, просто страшно смотреть на то как там вообще что-либо работает. Ситуация такая, хочу добавить на страницу jQuery слайдер, но при добавление JavaScript для формирования слайдера, страница не отображается, просто кусок след. вида:

```
<html> <head></head> <body></body> </html>
```

Консоль firebug'а ничего не показывает.

Думал, что `jQuery.noConflict();` поможет, но увы!

Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите пожалуйста, что делать в такой ситуации! Заранее благодарен.

Вот башка сайта:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>{$APPLICATION->GetTitle()}</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/about/branches/jquery.qtip.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/about/branches/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/about/branches/jquery.qtip.js"></script>   

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/lightbox.css" />
<style type="text/css">
@import url(/css/base.css);
@import url(/css/scroll.css);
@import url(/css/main.css);
@import url(/css/sec.css);
</style>

<!-- RedHelper Онлайн консультант -->
<script id="rhlpscrtg" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="async"
    src="http://web.redhelper.ru/service/main.js?c=betep"></script>
<!--/Redhelper -->

<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
@import url(/css/ie.css);
</style>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
@import url(/css/ie6.css);
</style>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
@import url(/css/ie55.css);
</style>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 5.500]>
<style type="text/css">
@import url(/css/ie5.css);
</style>
<![endif]-->

<style type="text/css" media="print">
@import url(/css/true_print.css);
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") >= 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") >= 0 )
document.write("<style type='text/css'>@import url(/css/ff.css);</style>");
else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.charAt(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera")+6) < 9)
document.write("<style type='text/css'>@import url(/css/op.css);</style>");
else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.charAt(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera")+6) == 9)
document.write("<style type='text/css'>@import url(/css/_op.css);</style>");
//-->
</script>

{literal}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jsScroller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jsScrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher:'3c457ac5-0d8d-4970-b98e-4a0705621427'});</script>
{/literal}
<!-- ~~~ -->
{$APPLICATION->ShowHead()}
<!-- ~~~ -->

{$pageContent->components.FLASH}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bank.js" ></script>

<style type="text/css">
@import url(/css/acc_menu.css);
</style>

<style type="text/css">
@import url(/css/sposobi_menu.css);
</style>

</head>
```

А это то что пытаюсь подключить:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528
      });
    });
  </script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Почему пустой html такой получается? Как вы добавляете "любой плагин", покажите код?

Comment: @Артёмыч да дело в том, что вы не даете данных для решения проблемы, я много с чем могу помочь с чем не сталкивался.

Comment: тут темплейтный движок, *какой* ? посмотрите во вкладке network, там 500 наверняка.

Comment: @eicto движок Битрикс, во вкладке network ничего нету :( за исключением одного несчастного GET запроса который cookies посылает, картиночку приложил

Comment: а получает то он чего ? 200 с пустой html ? обратитесь в техподдержку 1с :)

Comment: @eicto да нет же, зачем в техподдержку сразу, на Битриксе все нормально работает, любой код, просто в этом видимо что-то вызывает конфликт

Comment: если выдает 200, но при этом скрывает ошибку, то это бага. поэтому. js тут ни причем. скорее всего у вас падает php.

Comment: @eicto а php тут причем? если я кусок кода JS убираю то все снова начинает работать, вот это убираю и все работает. `<script> $(function(){ $("#slides").slidesjs({ width: 940, height: 528 }); }); </script>`

Comment: @Артёмыч, подключите [jQuery Migrate](http://jquery.com/download/). У меня подозрение, что плагин со свежей версией библиотеки не дружит.

Comment: @Deonis (((( не помогает ничего, блин в чем же дело...

Comment: @Артёмыч, что значит не помогает? jQuery Migrate показывает (*в консоли!*) возможные проблемы/нестыковки в вашем коде. Как вариант, подключите какой-нибудь другой слайдер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделайте вот так

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    jQuery(function(){
      jQuery("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528
      });
    });
  </script>
```

или так:

```
{literal}
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    jQuery(function(){
      jQuery("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528
      });
    });
  </script>
{/literal}
```

у вас явно internal server error, потому-что $ в темплейте.

Comment: Пффффф! Оценка ПЯТЬ! Спасибо, уважаемы!

Comment: Это все Smarty!!!!